# Why cannot import `dotenv-python` module when the python file runs from Java?

Tags: python, java, spring, environment-variables, python-dotenv

This script is contained in my Spring Boot application. when I send the request to run this script it will automatically run. I used the `py4j` library to make the connection between Java and Python. I used this method to run Python files from Java.

```java
public void runScript(String file){
        try {
            String pythonScriptPath = "./src/main/java/com/api/air_quality/python/" + file + ".py";
            String pythonExecutablePath = "C:\\Users\\KAVI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe";
            String command = pythonExecutablePath + " " + pythonScriptPath;

            // Append the cached data to the command
            for (Double value : airQualityDataCache.get()) {
                command += " " + value;
            }

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // output
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // error
            BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(line);
            }

            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                System.out.println("Python script exited with code: " + exitCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the python file I want to add `.env` variables.

```py
from time import sleep
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys
import requests
import os
# to ignore warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


class AirHumidityModelPython:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gateway = JavaGateway()
        self.java_model = self.gateway.entry_point

        with open("./AI_Models/airHumidity_model.pkl", 'rb') as f:
            self.model = pickle.load(f)

    def predict_air_humidity(self, features):
        try:
            features_2d = np.array(features).reshape(1, -1)
            prediction = self.model.predict(features_2d)[0]

            url = os.getenv("SPRINGBOOT_URL_PYTHON")
            spring_boot_url = url+"/airHumidity"

            # Send the prediction to the Spring Boot endpoint
            response = requests.post(spring_boot_url, json=float(prediction))
            # print(response.text)

            return prediction
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle any errors during prediction
            return str(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    # instance
    air_humidity_model = AirHumidityModelPython()
    
    # dummy_features = [[1.5, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 7.7, 9.4, 10.0]]
    data_from_java = [float(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
    result = air_humidity_model.predict_air_humidity(data_from_java)
    # result = air_humidity_model.java_model.Message()
```

The workflow is in this case, the user sends the values array to the springboot backend then the springboot service runs the above first method. it will run the Python file. Then it makes the prediction and sends the predicted value to the springboot backend again. Spring Boot caches the Python requested value and sends it to the user as a response.

The problem is `python-dotenv` occurs this error when runs the file

```
import dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

I installed the correct `python-dotenv` library into my project using the following command. I'm using `Python 3.10.4`

```
pip3 install python-dotenv
```

also tried,

```
pip3.10 install python-dotenv
```

this too.

```
pip3 uninstall -U python-dotenv
```

Then I ran the Python file directly without involving Java and it worked fine.

The error occurs only when a Python file runs through the Java method. Other Python imports don't make any errors.

Comment: `python -m pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: i am not sure why the code needs the `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`. It is usually a bad sign.

Comment: I tried this sir. With `python`, `python3`, `pip`, and `pip3` commands also. But still, the same problem happens

Comment: can you run a simple test file (without all the other imports and code and just the `dotenv`) on your system ?

Comment: I used filter warnings because my prediction module pops a warning it needs to factor names for X. In my case, I don't need to provide those names with the request. Without filter warning, my server console gets warnings every each predicted request. That's why I removed the warnings.

Yes sir I tried the test method too. just only using `.env` import and print methods. Every time works fine when directly running the file. The problem comes when it's run from the Java method

Comment: Odd place for the Python executable. Shouldn't that be off Program Files? You would strengthen your code by using `ProcessBuilder::inheritIO` instead of `Runtime.exec` as well as greatly simplify it. `Process p = new ProcessBuilder(List.of(pythonExecutablePath, pythonScriptPath)).InheritIO().start();` Your reading code can now go

Comment: I found a simple solution. The reason behind the problem is I loaded python.exe from the device drive and my `venv` folder held in the project root. I made the python.exe path also get from the project folder and sat appended the system paths for the library folder from the python file. Now it works! Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because I loaded the `python.exe` from the device drive and the `lib` folder from the root `venv`. When I'm trying to execute the Python file from Java, It can't load some activation-needed libraries. The reason is executer and library are in separate locations. So I modified a few things in my code.
In python file,

```py
venv_path = "../../../../../../../venv"
sys.path.append(venv_path + '/Lib/site-packages')
```

I appended the environment `venv` folder path as a system path. Now this file path works as it came from the system.

in java method,

```java
String venvPath = "./venv";
String pythonExecutablePath = venvPath + "/Scripts/python.exe";
String pythonScriptPath = "./src/main/java/com/api/air_quality/python/" + file + ".py";
String command = pythonExecutablePath + " " + pythonScriptPath;
```

I changed the python executable path as gets from the `venv` root folder also. Now this code works fine and it will not get any problems in it's deployment too.